# Which set did this sealed bag of mostly grey LEGO bricks come from?

Tags: set-identification

I bought a sealed bag of LEGO bricks with no box or directions and I am trying to figure out which set it is. It is all grey, black, and clear pieces and looks to be 100-150 pieces. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This is an inner bag of a larger set, not a full set. It is hard to tell which set it could be, as the pieces are too common to narrow it down from just this one image. I did look up the 3x4 hinge-plate, as that was the most uncommon, but it still appears in 45 sets, so we would need some other clues to narrow it down further. Here are the sets the hinge-plate appears in: https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=44570&colorID=86&in=A

Answer (score 5):

As I mentioned in my comment to OP's original question, this is an inner bag of a larger set, not a full set. It is a bit hard to tell which set it could be, as the pieces are too common to narrow it down from just one image. I did look up the 3x4 hinge-plate, as that was the most uncommon, but it still appears in 45 sets: https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=44570&colorID=86&in=A

Upon more careful inspection, and narrowing down the pieces even further, it appears that this is the gray/black bag from the #10702 LEGO Classic Creative Building set: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=10702-1#T=S&O=

I came to this conclusion by verifying some of the other pieces in the set from the BrickLink Catalog, and also noticing that the 23mm D. x 7mm Offset Tread Black Tire only appears in the above mentioned LEGO Classic set from the list of 45 sets with the 3x4 hinge-plate.

Comment: Impressive amount of effort you put in. I just noticed that all the elements looked common and decided not to spend my time on it. It's good that someone else did.

Comment: The power of lots of eyes looking at the same image is amazing, but I still get impressed by the great set-ident answers on this site.

Comment: I was also going to pass after checking on the hinge-plate, but it was bugging me I couldn't answer right away, so I got back to it. I hate to be defeated by questions like this. :D